# TypeError: R[o5R.F6s] is not a function in changing states in phaser box2d

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

i build my game using `phaser.2.4.3.min.js` and `phaser.2.2.2.box2d.min.js`
When trying to change states this error is being raised `TypeError: R[o5R.F6s] is not a function` and i can't seem to figure out the problem

PS : i took The source code of box2d plugin from the example folder in phaser , and i did not purchase the full plugin yet i was just testing it .

is there anyway to fix this issue ?

here is the game code : http://jsfiddle.net/fbdtq1tg/5/

and here where the error is raised :

```
SetGameOver: function () {
            this.game.state.start("TheGame");
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I cant understand I didn't get any TypeError but 'Uncaught Error: The Box2D physics system has not been implemented yet.' when run it in my editor.

Comment: did you see the jsfiddle example i provided ? please check my edit

Comment: which line you edited ? its not showing any result.

Comment: i did not edit any line i just posted a screenshot of the error , and if you run the example you can see the error ( try to run the example and click 3 times inside the canvas so the joint will appear and your move count will be reduced to `0` so the `Gameover` function will be raised and the error will be shown

Comment: I have tried my level best to resolve the problem but the same error happens to me. I didn't found any bug in your code.

Comment: i know my problem is in this error is it a library related error or it's something i did ?

Comment: I suggest you to separate GameOver and TheGame state into two javascript file then call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems clear: the script is trying to execute a function, but this variable isn't a function.

What happens: `box2d.m_gravity = box2d.clone();` but  `R[o5R.F6s]()` is the string "clone" and not a function. R = box2d, so the the script is trying to execute a function(`R[o5R.F6s]()`. o5R is an object with a lot of functions in it but the requested `F6s` is a string("clone").

So, I did some research why `box2d.b2world = function(gravity){...this.m_gravity = gravity.Clone();.. }` and it seems to be a bug.

Check out following links:

- http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/13753-changing-states-with-box2d-causes-crash/
- https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues/1884

Comment: actually the reason this error occurred is because i was using an old version of `phaser.min.js`  , i got the new version of `phaser.js` and it work fine . thank you for your answer

Comment: That's whay they said in the first link :) I'm glad you have solved your problem.